# How do I store multiple XLWT worksheets in a single excel file as separate sheets/tabs and preserve the formatting?

Tags: python, excel, xlrd, xlwt, xlutils

```
def _getOutCell(outSheet, colIndex, rowIndex):
    row = outSheet._Worksheet__rows.get(rowIndex)
    if not row: return None
    cell = row._Row__cells.get(colIndex)
    return cell

def setOutCell(outSheet, col, row, value):
    """ Change cell value without changing formatting. """
    previousCell = _getOutCell(outSheet, col, row)
    outSheet.write(row, col, value)
    if previousCell:
        newCell = _getOutCell(outSheet, col, row)
        if newCell:
            newCell.xf_idx = previousCell.xf_idx

rs_template_input = xlrd.open_workbook(<path to file>, formatting_info=True)

rs_copy_1 = xlutils.copy.copy(rs_template_input)
rs_copy_2 = xlutils.copy.copy(rs_template_input)

rs_template_sheet_1 = rs_copy_1.get_sheet(0)
rs_template_sheet_2 = rs_copy_2.get_sheet(0)

setOutCell(rs_template_sheet_1, 2, 3, 'project 1')
setOutCell(rs_template_sheet_2, 2, 3, 'project 2')
```

I want **rs_template_sheet_1** and **rs_template_sheet_2** to be two sheets/tabs in one excel file and *preserve the formatting*

PS: The function **setOutCell** is used to write to a cell in the excel and preserve the formatting